# How to use State value outside the function in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 2 files, Header and App, App is my parent file and header is child, I have design a button in header for open and close Sidebar, But i am unable to do that. My question is How to pass state value from header to App file.
Here's the code

```
import Header from 'components/Header';
import FirstSection from 'components/FirstSection';
import SecondSection from 'components/SecondSection';
import ThirdSection from 'components/ThirdSection';
import FourthSection from 'components/FourthSection';
import Sidebar from 'components/Sidebar';
import toggleState from 'components/Header';
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Header setToggleState={toggleState}/>

      <div className="row mlr0 w-100">

    <div className={`pl-0 a ${toggleState ? 'col-md-3': 'd-none'}`} id="showOnClick">
<Sidebar />
</div>
<div className="col-md-9" id="fullScreen">
<FirstSection/>
<SecondSection/>
<ThirdSection/>
<FourthSection/>
 <div className="row justify-content-center">
  <img src={require("./images/Aqomi_Logo_Pink_Web_Small.png")} className="pb17"/>
</div> 
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import App from './../App';

export default function Header(props){
  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(true);

  function changeClass(){

   setToggleState(!toggleState);

  }
    return(
        <div>
             <li className="nav-item"><a className="navbar-brand pl-1 hm "  onClick={changeClass}> 
             <img src={require("./../images/line.png")} height="23px" className={toggleState.className} />
               </a></li>


        </div>
        )
}
```

Header.js

Comment: `useState(true);` probably needs to use the state passed in via props.

Comment: either you have to move `toggleState` to `App.js` or use renderProps to pass data to  Parent or using redux

Comment: well, you need to declare `toggleState`, `setToggleState` in App, then pass them to Header via props.

Comment: Define and keep the state in App and pass it down to whichever component needs it. Also your import statement 'toggleState from “components/Header”' actually imports the Header component under the name toggleState.

Comment: @WilsonLiao can you share the code please, how to pass them to header via props?/

Comment: @MarioSubotic, yes i already import toggleState , but still it's not working

Comment: You can not import state from another component like that. Just copy paste the const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState() from Header to App

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare toggleState, setToggleState in App, then pass them to Header via props.

```
//in App
const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(true);

render() {
  return <Header toggleState={toggleState} setToggleState={setToggleState} />
}


//in Header
function Header(props) {
// get the value
const { toggleState } = props

//call the function
props.setToggleState(toggleState)

...
```

Comment: const { toggleState } = this.props , it's a functional component so i think 'this.' is not working. So what should i write instead of 'this.props.setToggleState(toggleState)'

Comment: how about that? I just modified the snippet.